# Extra space in Webkit Browsers? (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

In webkit browsers such as chrome and safari, there is extra space at the bottom of the page on my website.

The website is http://www.xblakej.com/

My style sheet can be found at http://www.xblakej.com/style.css

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Not seeing it in Chrome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iFrame is causing the issue, when I remove it with the Chrome Inspector, the space goes away.

Set your iFrame to `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`